# Trim a Priority Queue

Tags: c#, priority-queue

***Requirement:***
I have a Max-Priority Queue with ***n*** elements. Now I want to keep only the ***m***-maximum elements (where ***m***<=***n***) and drop the rest from the queue. In other words, I want to trim the queue.

How do I achieve this?

One way that I could come up with is, dequeue ***m*** elements and put them into another queue. Then assign the reference of the new queue into that of the old queue.

```
public static PriorityQueue<int> TrimPQueue(PriorityQueue<int> paraQueue, int newSize)
{
    if (newSize >= paraQueue.Count)
        return paraQueue;
    PriorityQueue<int> newQueue = new PriorityQueue<int>(PriorityQueueType.Maximum);
    for (int i = 1; i < newSize + 1; i++)
    {
        int temp = paraQueue.Dequeue();
        newQueue.Add(temp);
    }
    return newQueue;
}
```

Isn't there a better way to do this? I would prefer if there's a way to trim the working-queue, without having to create a new queue-object.

Comment: You're using an object, so you don't need to return a PriorityQueue<int> from this function... i would just dequeue X elements and then, the class that is calling this function could use the "trimmed" queue after that

Comment: And when you will know this M? Can you just insert while is smaller than newSize?

Comment: Thanks for helping Crasher :) When we call `Dequeue()`, we **drop** the **maximum** m elements, right? I do not want to drop those. I want to drop the **minimum** m elements.

Comment: And this m is hard-coded. It's decided even at the compile time. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: Is it your implementation of the PriorityQueue?

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt No Håkan; I'm `using NGenerics.DataStructures.Queues;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PriorityQueue implements the IEnumerable interface so you could use that in combination with the Linq extension method Last():

```
while (paraQueue.Count > newSize)
{
  paraQueue.Remove(paraQueue.Last());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Håkan! This seems like a better way than creating another queue-object.